# Duplicate headers and Calling the file in the wrong path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create and showing a pdf from my webpage by clicking a link. But when the system has to show it goes something wrong.

When I use this command

> return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");

It shows a empty pdf file:

> ///C:/Users/Me/Downloads/C--Apps-MyWebSolution-MyWeb-Documenten-MyList_198721.pdf

It is saved as: C:\Apps\MyWebSolution\MyWeb\Documenten\MyList_198721%20.pdf

And when I use this command:

> return File(fileStream, "application/pdf", fullFileName);

then I get an error message:

> ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION

What am I doing wrong?

```
public FileStreamResult PDFGenerator(string html, string fileName)
{
    string fullFileName = Server.MapPath("~/Documenten/" + fileName + ".pdf");
    Stream fileStream = CreatePDF(html, fullFileName);

    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fullFileName);

    //return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
    return File(fileStream, "application/pdf", fullFileName);
}
```

If I had to post more. I'll do it. But I don't think it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my result that works:

This is calling from the View

```
    public HttpResponseBase HitlijstNaarPdf(int? AID_Hitlijst = 0)
    {
        SelectPeriode(AID_Hitlijst);
        var model = new HitlijstModel();

        GetHitlijstSettings();
        string sHtmlInhoud = ViewRenderer.RenderView("Hitlijst", model, ControllerContext);
        string fileName = "Hitlijst_" + AID_Hitlijst.ToString() + ".pdf";

        return CreatePDF(sHtmlInhoud, fileName);
    }

    private HttpResponseBase CreatePDF(string html, string fileName)
    {
        string convertingTool = Server.MapPath("~/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe ");

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(convertingTool);
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process myProcess = Process.Start(psi);
        myProcess.WaitForExit();
        myProcess.Close();

        string fullFileName = Server.MapPath("~/Documenten/" + fileName);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fullFileName))
        {
            Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, new FileStream(fullFileName, FileMode.Create));
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDocument.Open();

            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDocument, new StringReader(html));
            pdfDocument.Close();
        }

        Response.Clear();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(fullFileName); 
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);

        return Response;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you need to `.Seek` stream to the beginning (usually when you write to a file `Position` points to end/last written location).

Second issue is somewhat self explanatory as you set "content-disposition" header twice - manualy and via `File(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explenation

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. Have you tried removing (or commenting-out) the line where you add the header to the response? returning the File(...) may well add the header for you, resulting in the header being specified twice which would lead to the error you're seeing.
2. The File(...) should specify the `filename.pdf`, not the entire path to the file.
3. Note that your filename should not contain any spaces or any non-alphanumeric characters. This is recommended-against by [RFC 6266, Appendix D](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#page-13).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explenation