# How to open PDF file in browser through controller in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

ASP.NET/Mono MVC4 controller sends pdf file to browser:

```
public ActionResult Pdf() {
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=myfile.pdf");
return File(<pdf content>, "application/pdf", "myfile.pdf");
}
```

For single page file Chrome shows pdf content in new tab.

For multi page files file is not show. Chrome throws error

> ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION

instead.

If line

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=myfile.pdf");
```

is removed according to

[Duplicate headers and Calling the file in the wrong path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334290/duplicate-headers-and-calling-the-file-in-the-wrong-path)

Chrome offers to download PDF file. It does not show PDF in new tab automatically.
How to force Chrome to show multi-page PDF content in new tab automatically ?

ASP.NET MVC4 application runs in Mono and Windows. wkhtmltopdf is used to create PDF files from Razor views.

Comment: For our app, we are opening up PDF's in a new window; all we do to return it is return the byte array of the PDF doc with a content type of "application/pdf"; this opens the document directly in a new tab (since it is supported by the browser).  This is with single or multi page documents...

Comment: `return File(<pdf content>, "application/pdf", "myfile.pdf");` without inline extra header causes only pdf download, not opening. What code you use so that browser opens it directly ?

Comment: Try removing "myfile.pdf", and also make sure that the returning of the file is happening in a new tab.

Comment: I tried `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline")` but same error occurs. PDF opening button is defiend as `<input type="submit" formaction="/Report/Pdf" class="btn btn-info" formtarget="_blank" value="PDF">`