# How to create valid file name in http header from user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.NET 7 MVC application running in Debian with Apache should open PDF files in browser.
Implamented solution from     [Make a file open in browser instead of downloading it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411335/make-a-file-open-in-browser-instead-of-downloading-it/)

and

[how to specify name for saving pdf from browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050591/how-to-specify-name-for-saving-pdf-from-browser)

Controller contains code

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> OpenPdf()
  {
    byte[] pdf = CreatePdf();
    string filename = "\",'õäöü";
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename={filename}.pdf");
    return File(result, "application/pdf");
    }
```

Issues:

1. Chrome throws error ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION
   Accoding to [Duplicate headers and Calling the file in the wrong path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334290/duplicate-headers-and-calling-the-file-in-the-wrong-path)

This is caused by characters  like

```
',"
```

in header.

2. If those characters are removed, error illegar control character in header occurs only in Apache (running from Visual Studio IDE works OK). This is probably caused by õäöü characters.

How to encode file name in http header ?

According to [Duplicate headers and Calling the file in the wrong path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334290/duplicate-headers-and-calling-the-file-in-the-wrong-path)  only alphanumeric characters are allowed.
How to convert any unicode string to meaningful legal file name for header?

In this case üõöä should replaced to uooa characters, quotes, samces and comma can removed. However file name comes from user input and may contain any unicode characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use UrlEncode for file names, Url names, etc.

```
var encodedFileName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName + ".pdf",  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename={encodedFileName}");
```

Comment: Using this code, if file name contains space, + appers in file name proposed for pdf saving from Chrome, e.q "My file" becomes "My+file". How to fix this so that space in file name appears on pdf save?